# How do these JS code snippets work?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading about closures, and I had difficulty understanding the difference between these 2 code snippets:

```
var myElements = [ /* DOM Collection */ ];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    myElements[i].onclick = function() {
        alert( 'You clicked on: ' + i );
    };
}
```

The above code should only display `i` as 99 for every onclick

```
function getHandler(n) {
    return function() {
        alert( 'You clicked on: ' + n );
    };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    myElements[i].onclick = getHandler(i);
}
```

And this code above displays the correct value of 'i' for every element click event!

I can't understand why the 1st one doesn't display the correct value of `i`. And if not, why does the 2nd one display the correct value??

They were taken from [this link](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/closures-in-javascript/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I can't understand why the 1st one doesn't display the correct value of `i`.

It's because the closure doesn't capture the *value* of `i`, but rather, the actual local variable `i`. When you go on to change the value of `i`, the closure sees those changes, because it's still using that same variable.

> And if not, why does the 2nd one display the correct value??

Because in the second one, the closure is capturing the local variable `n`, which never changes thereafter. (Later calls to `getHandler` have a completely new local variable `n`; this is important, not just for closures, but also for support for recursion. Otherwise different calls to a function could accidentally mess with each other's variables!)

Answer (score 1):

Both of them display the value when the click happens.

In the first one, there is only one `i`, and it is `99` when the click happens.

In the second one, there is a new `n` for each time the `getHandler` is called.

Answer (score 0):

The first displays 99 for each because, by the time the function is called, the value of `i` is 99.

The second displays the correct values because you close over `i` (via the parameter `n`). That means that while `i` will continue to change, `n` retains the value at the time the function was called.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example, the onclick function is created in the loop, with a reference to `i`, but it is not executed until the click occurs. When the click is triggered, the function executes, and reads `i`, which is now set to 99.

In the second example, `getHandler(i)` is executed immediately, returning a function with reference to `n`. (This is why the returned function is called a closure: it has "closed" over the value passed in). In this new function scope, `n` is equal to the value that was passed in--the value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`onclick` function is destined to be fired later.

In the first case the value of i is lost till the event is fired,

But in the second case the value of i is is copied & saved for later.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the 2nd example works and the 1st doesn't is to do with scope. In the first example, the variable `i` is stored within the global scope, and read when you click a button. As you've completed the loop, `i` is 99. If you had been able to click button 1 while still in the loop, you would get whatever the current value of `i` is. (Which isn't possible by the way).

In the second example, a copy of `i` is stored within the function `getHandler`, which will not change when you change `i` in the loop. `getHandler` is the scope the (unnamed) function you return, and as such that's the variable it reads.

Answer (score 0):

The "i" variable is bound to the scope, you can create a new scope with a function evaluated at the moment when "i" has the right value

You can implement this behavior:

```
var myElements = [{}, {}];

for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) {
    myElements[i].onclick =
        function(i) {
            return function() {
                alert( 'You clicked on: ' + i );
            }
        }(i); // <- This behavior is the important one
}
```

Greetings